# How to urlencode part of the url only?

Tags: php, wordpress, urlencode, shortcode

I have a WordPress website, with two custom post types, `book` and `article`.

Due to a design requirement, I want to create a shortcode to `return` the `url` of the post featured image. I could not use the built-in function `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()` because I have my images cached on the `wordpress.com` network (using `Jetpack`) and this function  returns the cached `url`, which does not work with my design requirement.

I created the following shortcode:

```
function wp_featured_image_url( $atts ) {
   global $post;
    $url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID); 
    if (is_singular($post_types = 'book')) {      
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() )  {
                return $url;    
                    }
        else {
                echo 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/year/month/generic-featured-image-for-books.png';  
            }   
        }

    else
        if (is_singular($post_types = 'article')) {
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() )  {
                    return $url;    
                    }
            else {
                echo 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/year/month/generic-featured-image-for-articles.png';   
                }   
        }       

}
add_shortcode( 'featured_image_url', 'wp_featured_image_url' );
```

It works fine, except that the image file titles are in Arabic (UTF-8), so this function will return the `url`like this:

`https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/كلام-عربي-كتير.jpg`

I want it to return the `urlencode` of the image file name only. However, if I changed `return $url;` to `return urlencode($url);` or `return rawurlencode($url);` it will return the whole url as `urlencode`:

`https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2019%2F10%2F%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A-%D9%83%D8%AA%D9%8A%D8%B1.jpg`

I want to be able to adjust the function so that the first part of the `url` stays intact, and only the image file name gets `urlencode`, like this:

`https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A-%D9%83%D8%AA%D9%8A%D8%B1.jpg`

Can someone please point me to the right direction?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the url to two parts: the first - everything from the start to last slash, and the second - everything else which has no slash until the end.
Then combine them back, urlencoding only the second part.

```php
<?php

  function url_onlyfile_encode($url) {
    if (preg_match('#^(.*/)([^/]+)$#u', $url, $res)) {
      return $res[1] . urlencode($res[2]);
    }
    return urlencode($url);
  }

  // test
  $s = 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/كلام-عربي-كتير.jpg';
  print url_onlyfile_encode($s);
  // https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A-%D9%83%D8%AA%D9%8A%D8%B1.jpg
```

**UPDATED**

If you want the fastest code, try to work directly with strings, like this:

```
  function url_onlyfile_encode($url) {
    $p = strrpos($url, '/'); // Find the last slash
    if ($p !== false) {
      // Encode only the part after the last slash
      return substr($url, 0, $p + 1) . urlencode(substr($url, $p + 1)); 
    } else {
      return urlencode($url);
    }
  }
```

I made a simple test with loops like:

```
  // test string
  $s = 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/كلام-عربي-كتير.jpg';

  $repeat_count = 1000000;

  $tm = microtime(true);
  for ($i = 0 ; $i < $repeat_count ; $i++) {
    tested_func($s);
  }
  $tm = microtime(true) - $tm;
  print "Time: " . round($tm * 1000) . " ms" . PHP_EOL;
```

The full code is [here](https://pastebin.com/fhR6nWRC)

The results are as follows:

*php 5.6.40:*

> (Blank): 17 ms
>
> AterLux (regexp): 1907 ms
>
> AterLux (str): 641 ms
>
> Emanuele: 3583 ms
>
> Petter Harsem: 1269 ms
>
> Yeeooow: 1884 ms

*(Note: "Blank" is an empty loop without any function call inside)*

*php 7.3.4 (x64):*

> (Blank): 9 ms
>
> AterLux (regexp): 499 ms
>
> AterLux (str): 284 ms
>
> Emanuele: 2820 ms
>
> Petter Harsem: 477 ms
>
> Yeeooow: 804 ms

As you can see, the variant with `strrpos` is the fastest in either case.

Among others, Petter Harsem's `explode` -> `count` -> `implode` shows better results than regular expressions, although in php7 the difference is not that big.

Yeeooow's answer, which also uses `explode` and `count`, but uses `for`-loop to assemble the string back, works faster than regular expressions on php5 but shows twice greater time in php7.

Emanuele's answer, which involves call to `parse_url` is the most time consuming.

In either way the difference is within couple of microseconds, which is in the real world is negligible.

Comment: Hm i didnt know you could delimit regex using `#`

Comment: Thanks AterLux. Just wondering if there is a performance preference between your solution and @Peter Harsem's solution below? I have thousands of posts. Is there a solution that is better than the other when implemented on large scale?

Comment: @AtefWagih I have expended the answer

Answer (score 0):

Antoher way would be, crude but easier to undersand.

```
<?php
$url = "https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/كلام-عربي-كتير.jpg";
$e = explode('/', $url); // seperate it ou using the /
$c = count($e); // get the number of elements
$ne = $c - 1; // the last element
$file = $e[$ne]; // كلام-عربي-كتير.jpg
$newURL = ''; // empty var
for ($i = 0; $i < $ne; $i++) {
    $newURL .= $e[$i] . '/'; // rebuild the url
}
echo $newURL . urlencode($file); //put it all togeather again
```

response would be

```
https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/%D9%83%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A-%D9%83%D8%AA%D9%8A%D8%B1.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, you'll need to split the url, apply the `urlencode` to the file name, and then put the URL back together. There are several ways you could to this, for example with regex to pick out the part after the last `/`.

Or another simple solution, using [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
// Split the URL on '/'
$urlParts = explode('/', $url);

// URL encode the last part
$numParts = count($urlParts);
$urlParts[$numParts - 1] = urlencode($urlParts[$numParts - 1]);

// Put the parts back together to a string
$formattedUrl = implode('/', $urlParts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$url = "https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/كلام-عربي-كتير.jpg";
$parsed = parse_url($url);
$pathFragments = explode('/', $parsed['path']);
$fileAndExt = array_pop($pathFragments);
list($file, $ext) = explode(".", $fileAndExt);

return $parsed['scheme']."://".$parsed['host'].implode("/", $pathFragments)."/".urlencode($file).".".$ext;
```